# How to localize text with TextSpan widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I am using `Flutter Intl` android studio plugin for ready made localization.
But in my scenario i have the widget like this,

```dart
Text.rich(
      TextSpan(
        text: 'It is time to',
        children: [
          TextSpan(
            text: 'Stay Relaxed',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

So how can i translate a single message "It is time to Stay Relaxed" and use in `Text.rich` widget?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

EDIT: More explanation
The text can not be handled as one piece. Each part of needs to be handled separately. Because from the TextSpans concern, those are different texts. So you need to create two different texts within the arb file.

From the Flutter Intl's perspective, these are two different components. TextSpan has its own drawing perspective. That is why you need to create two different components for these items.

There are packages out there like https://pub.dev/packages/localized_rich_text but I did not use it. In our app I use it like the following.

Flutter Intl creates the localized elements as follows:

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).tranlatedElement;

//or
AppLocalizations.current.tranlatedElement;
```

So your Code should be like the following

```
Text.rich(
   TextSpan(
     text: AppLocalizations.current.relaxTextPrefix,
     children: [
       TextSpan(
         text: AppLocalizations.current.relaxTextSuffix,
         style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
         ),
       ),
     ],
   ),
 ),
)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is meaning of `tranlatedElement` and `relaxTextPrefix`?

Comment: Of course, I will write here and explain it in the question as well. The text can not be handled as one piece. Each part of needs to be handled separately. Because from the TextSpans concern, those are different texts. So you need to create two different texts within the arb file.

Comment: This is not a good solution because different languages use different sentence structures. When you translate "I danced _all night_" into German, it becomes "I have _all night_ danced" which requires a different number of pieces to emphasize "all night"